# My vscode extension (.NET Runtime Install Tool) gives an error on startup

Tags: c#, .net, vscode-extensions

I've tried updating my dotnet to v7.0.401 and tried reinstalling the extension.
It used to work, but it doesn't anymore, my brother's extension started working again about 2 days ago but mine didn't.(both times it changed, we didn't change anything)
I don't know, what else to try, but here is the error (tl. = translation inserted by me):

```
Using dotnet configured on PATH
Dotnet path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
Activating C# standalone...
waiting for named pipe information from server...
[stdout] {"pipeName":"\\\\.\\pipe\\32893003-39b4-48d8-9772-ea73a8b6c7fa"}
received named pipe information from server
attempting to connect client to server...
client has connected to server
[Info  - 12:39:12 PM] [Program] Language server initialized
[Info  - 12:39:13 PM] [LanguageServerProjectSystem] Loaded MSBuild in-process from C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401
[Info  - 12:39:13 PM] [LanguageServerProjectSystem] Loading c:\Users\perda\Desktop\Programs\programfiles\unity Projects\MyProject\MyProject.sln...
[Error - 12:39:17 PM] [LanguageServerProjectSystem] Exception thrown while loading c:\Users\perda\Desktop\Programs\programfiles\unity Projects\MyProject\Assembly-CSharp.csproj StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Die Sequenz enthält keine Elemente.(tl. the sequence doesn't contain any elements.)
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync[TResult](RequestId id, String targetName, IReadOnlyList'1 arguments, IReadOnlyList'1 positionalArgumentDeclaredTypes, IReadOnlyDictionary'2 namedArgumentDeclaredTypes, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isParameterObject)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer.HostWorkspace.LanguageServerProjectSystem.LoadOrReloadProjectAsync(ProjectToLoad projectToLoad, BuildHostProcessManager buildHostProcessManager, BuildHost inProcessBuildHost, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Features/LanguageServer/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer/HostWorkspace/LanguageServerProjectSystem.cs:line 241
RPC server exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Die Sequenz enthält keine Elemente.(tl. the sequence doesn't contain any elements.)
      bei(tl. at) System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source)
      bei(tl. at) Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild.BuildHost.BuildHost.EnsureMSBuildLoaded(String projectFilePath)
      bei(tl. at) Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild.BuildHost.BuildHost.IsProjectFileSupportedAsync(String projectFilePath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

[Info  - 12:39:17 PM] [LanguageServerProjectSystem] Completed (re)load of all projects in 00:00:03.8970024
```

When i start vscode, the (.NET Runtime Install Tool) runs and should be working with the C# extension but instead it just gives this error and doesn't do anything.

Comment: I got an update for my c# extension and now it is fixed.